# Adding Master/Detail activity in Android Studio 3.0 throws errors

Tags: android, master-detail

I am just adding Master/Detail Activity in my project with default settings and getting following errors:

**Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
Required by:
    project :app > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

> No cached version of javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2 available for offline mode.**

and here is my build.gradle:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fasttrack.marileena.masterdetailapplication"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'*/
}
```

After commenting last two dependencies, the errors removed. Is it ok to delete them or by doing so will be problematic further??

Comment: You're building in Offline mode it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no real problem in deleting this dependencies, you can fix your compilation disabling the Offline work option. Go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle and uncheck the 'Offline work' option. Then try to resync again.